# Load strongly-name assembly from specific path?

Tags: c#, assembly.load

I have a strongly-named assembly, installed to a specific folder (and not the GAC).

The name as shown in Reflector is:

```
"Foo.Bar.TreeFrog, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ac88c4a8b22089b4"
```

and the path where it's installed is

```
"c:\\QueueBall"
```

Can I use `Assembly.Load` or `Assembly.LoadFrom` to load it, and if so how?

Can I ensure that the strong naming is honored, i.e. that the DLL I'm loading really is the one I'm expecting and not an imposter with the same name?

Comment: Tsk, tsk.  Creating your own folders directly off of the root of the drive is not a good idea.

Comment: @Joel -- not something I can control, alas. It's not my DLL and not from my installer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx):

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\QueueBall\Foo.Bar.TreeFrog.dll");
```

Note that this will also load referenced assemblies into the application domain running this code. If you don't want this behavior you could use the [LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) method.

---

UPDATE:

You can check the assembly identity before loading it to make sure that it has not been tampered with:

```
AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"c:\QueueBall\Foo.Bar.TreeFrog.dll");
byte[] key = an.GetPublicKey();
Version version = an.Version;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to also check that the strong name is correct -- i.e. that somebody has not swapped in their own DLL with the same file name but the wrong signature?