# Load multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, strongname

How can I load an assembly using its full display name from a location outside the application's bin path?

Usually one can load an assembly from a custom location with

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

This works, but it seems that for loading a strong-named assembly I need to specify its full display name such as in

```
Assembly myDll =
Assembly.Load("myDll, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b35aa32c18d4fb1");
```

But the problem here is that this only references assemblies that are in my probing path of my application.

So what if I have an assembly `dir1/asm.dll` and one assembly `dir2/asm.dll` and both have a strong name.

How can I load them during runtime?

Comment: sorry my answer was before the SN requirement, this post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103858/load-strongly-name-assembly-from-specific-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Runtime, you can specify additional directories to probe when loading an assembly via the following methods:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ClearPrivatePath();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath();
```

When the subdirectory names are already known during installation, you can also specify these additional directories in the app.config file in the `privatePath` attribute of the `<probing>` element.

Make also sure the file name is correct. When you have

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath("Subdir");

Assembly myDll = Assembly.Load("myDll, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b35aa32c18d4fb1");
```

then .net will look for a file named "mydll.dll" in the directory "Subdir" beneath the directory of the executable.

Comment: It's not working. I added the `AppedPrivatePath` call to point to my directory but my call to `Assembly.Load(...)` will still not find anything and gives me a FileNotFoundException!

Comment: How did you specify the path? Do not use a full path but the path relative to your application directory (where the *.exe resides)

Comment: I finally found the problem: If you call `AppendPrivatePath` multiple times after each other such as in e.g. `AppendPrivatePath(dir1); AppendPrivatePath(dir2); AppendPrivatePath(dir3);` it will also look for the assembly in this exact order. This means that if you have two assemblies with the same name and a different identity (such as a different version) it will take the first assembly that matches the assembly name by looking through the directories `dir1`, then `dir2` and then `dir3`. ...

Comment: ... If you want to load an assembly that is included in `dir2` and you have an assembly with the same name in `dir1` the plan will not succeed. The solution is to use `AppendPrivatePath`, as you suggested and to call `ClearPrivatePath` just before it, so that you always have only one path set.

Answer (score 0):

you can load any assembly from its location via loadfile ([example here](https://github.com/boxes-project/Core/blob/master/src/Boxes.Core/AssemblyReference.cs#L64))

if you want to take multiple versions of an assembly consider handling the  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve ([example here](https://github.com/boxes-project/Core/blob/master/src/Boxes.Core/Loading/IsolatedLoader.cs#L42))

the examples are from a small open source project, which will load dlls from a seperate a "packages" folder (allowing for packages to have their own copy of a [dependency](http://docs.dbones.co.uk/boxes.Loader-Overview.ashx), using the isolated loader)